# undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'

Tags: c++, g++, pthreads

I have written the following `T` class with `pthread`. When i compile this class using g++ -lpthread then it's working fine. But if i extend this class from another class `A` and compile all together it's returns an error; "undefined reference to pthread_cancel"

**Code:**

```
class T{
private:
    pthread_t thread;
public:
    void start(){
        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,&run,this);
    }
    void destroy_thread(){
        pthread_cancel(thread);
    }
    static void* run(void*){}
    ~Thread(){
        destroy_thread();
    }
};
```

**Next class:**

```
class A:T{
    A(){
      start();
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
int main(){
  A a;
  return 0;
}
```

**Compile:**

```
g++ -c T.cpp A.cpp Main.cpp -lpthread 
g++ -o out *.o
```

**Error:**
**undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'**

Comment: Do you have the `#include <pthread.h>` line somewhere?

Comment: Add -lpthread in your linker options

Answer (score 11):

Do this instead:

```
g++ -pthread -c T.cpp A.cpp Main.cpp
g++ -pthread -o out *.o
```

`-lpthread` is a *linker* flag, it's used only when linking, not compiling, so where you have it isn't correct - the linking part happens in the second step.

And generally don't use `-lpthread` anyway. Use `-pthread` both for compiling and linking.

From the GCC manual:

> Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.